# Locally exact vs globally exact

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Why the volume form in Sphere is locally exact but not globally exact? here the integral is integral $$\int_{S^n}w$$ with $$w = \frac{1}{r} \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{i-1} x_i dx_1 \cdots\hat{dx_i},\cdots dx_{n+1}. $$

Comment: As $w$ is an $n$-form on an $n$-dimensional manifold, it is automatically closed, so by the Poincaré Lemma, it is locally exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if it were globally exact, because $\partial S^n = \emptyset$, we'd have to have $\int_{S^n}\omega = 0$ by Stokes's Theorem.